# How to hyperlink to a file that partially matches the cell value

Tags: hyperlink

I am a VB novice and have spent the last 3 hours trying to copy and paste and rework other peoples answers similar to what I'm looking for to no avail:

My spreadsheet has one column with many rows.  All of the values in the rows virtually match the file names I want to link to except most have small differences.(ie. cell value is "RFI 246 Bld B-..." and filename is "RFI 246 Bldg B...".

The only things that are constant and unique to each pair of values and filenames is the sequence of the last 3 of the first 7 characters(RFI ***246***).

Is there a way to create hyperlinks from the cells to the pdf files by matching the first 7 characters in the cell to the first 7 characters in the filename?

Thank you

Comment: It's possible although the first 7 chars have to be unique for each file otherwise that would put you in a bit of choice problem. I'd be more than happy to help you if you answer that

Comment: 3 of the first 7 will be unique: RFI 001..., RFI 002..., etc.  Can it still work this way?

Comment: So each 3 chars never repeat for two files?

Comment: It's a numbering system, so 1-2 of the characters may repeat but the sequence for each file will be unique.